# android - Как создать ListView с разметкой из двух TextView?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

Мне нужно создать кастомный ListView в котором будет присутствовать разметка из двух TextView: один слева, второй - в центре. Затем оба нужно динамически заполнить элементами из ArrayList. Так вот, как такие провернуть? До этого приходилось работать только со стандартным адаптером и разметкой из одного TextView. Перерыл ВЕСЬ интернет, нахожу только статьи про создание адаптера из ImageView, CheckBox, RadioButton и Button. Про два TextView ничего нет.

Comment: Нет никакой особой разницы, какой виджет используется в разметке, но если прям вы не в силах даже поменять виджет по примеру, то интернет вы все же не дорыли видимо - [например, вот](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/). Так же, если вы используете БД, то работать надо напрямую с `Cursor` и  `CursorAdapter` - зачем бессмысленно перегонять данные из одной сущности в другую, абсолютно бесполезная трата ресурсов и скорости работы приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взять любой пример и по аналогии сделать под свои нужды. Кратко:

Создаете `xml` с разметкой для элементов (назвем `entry_one.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

В `avtivity`:

```
String [] arrOne={заполнение};
String [] arrTwo={заполнение};
...
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, arrOne,arrTwo));
```

сам адаптер:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
    String [] arrOne;
    Context context;
    String [] arrTwo;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] arrOne, String[] arrTwo) {
        this.arrOne=arrOne;
        context=mainActivity;
        this.arrTwo=arrTwo;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return result.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv2;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_one, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tv2=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);       
        holder.tv.setText(arrOne[position]);
        holder.tv2.setImageResource(arrTwo[position]);         
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO 
            //Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+arrOne[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });   
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня массив заполняется из базы данных. Я использую два ArrayList.Как перенести  из в класс? Не получается

Answer (score 0):

1. Отличий нет никаких при создании разметки из двух текстовых полей или `n` `m`-элементов. Так что берите любой пример и просто адаптируйте, убрав/заменив лишнее.
2. Лучше сразу делайте через `RecyclerView` - с `ListView` вы аццки намучаетесь реализуя `Viewholder`, коий в `RecyclerView` встроен по умолчанию.

Comment: Прямо таки адски ? :) Из вышенаписанного следует, что данные надо получать из БД, соответственно работать с курсором и вот тут уже можно "адски намучиться", прикручивая его к `RecyclerView`, который не имеет никаких базовых адаптеров. А вообще, человек, судя по всему, адски мучается и от простейших действий (замена виджета в разметке или массива на коллекцию), так что до холдеров еще не скоро дело дойдет, а с `RecyclerView` и вообще навсегда закончится.

Comment: @pavlofff, все, спасибо за ссылку, я  разобрался) просто код огромный, тут и работа с сервером и БД и куча массивов и путаницы возникли. потренировался на отдельной активности, вроде все понятно. дальше юзаю тему. а что лучше - ListView или RecyclerView?

Comment: @pavlofff, я просто из собственного опыта - когда перешёл на `RecyclerView` стало многое проще) Ну и плюс постоянно тут у нас вопросы на тему проблем с холдерами в `ListView`... Плюс очень приятные методы уведомления адаптера у `RecyclerView` есть) А про БД когда отвечал ещё не было тут инфы. Да и курсорам я не доверяю - как то и без них пока обходился)